# Distance between 2 co-ordinates in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am still very new to Java and I am tasked to do the following:

read in a set of coordinates, with a coordinate appearing on each line.
The input is terminated by a -1.
Each coordinate has an x and a y value. You must store these coordinates so that you can use
them later.
Next, you must write a method that calculates the distance between two coordinates, using the
Euclidean distance 
output the distance between the closest pair of points (ie. the pair of
points that has the smallest Euclidean distance)

Eclipse IDE doesn't show me what my error is

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class coordinates {

    public static double distance(int w, int x, int y, int z) {
        double xdist = Math.pow(x-w, 2);
        double ydist = Math.pow(z-y, 2);

        double output = Math.sqrt(xdist + ydist);

        return output;
    }



    public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String>storage = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<Integer>storageInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ArrayList<Double>storageDist = new ArrayList<Double>();

    String values = null;

    String inArray;
    String[]holder;
    int convert;

    while(values != "-1") {
        values = input.nextLine();
        storage.add(values);

    }
//convert coordinates to int
    for(int i = 0; i<storage.size();i++) {
        inArray = storage.get(i);
        holder = inArray.split(",");
        convert = Integer.parseInt(holder[i]);
        storageInt.add(convert);

    }
    //store distance
    for (int i=0;i<storageInt.size(); i++) {

        double dist = distance(storageInt.get(i), storageInt.get(i+1),storageInt.get(i+2),storageInt.get(i+3));
        storageDist.add(dist);

    }
    //smallest distance
    Collections.sort(storageDist);

    for (int i=0;i<storageDist.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(storageDist.get(0));
    }


    }
    }
```

Comment: what is the exact problem?

Comment: that's homework, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You had a nice attempt, but there were several problems.

1. Use `.equals()` to check for String equality. Instead of `values != "-1"`, you should use `!values.equals("-1")`.
2. If the user enters `-1`, you're adding that to `storage` before checking if it's `-1`. You should do this in the other order: check for `-1`, and only when it's not `-1` you add it `storage`.
3. After splitting on the comma, you have 2 `int`s in `holder`. Access them with indices `0` and `1`, not `i`.
4. Be careful how you iterate over `storageInt`. Notice that it has twice as many elements as `storage`, since each coordinate has 2 `int`s.
5. You want the closest among *any pair* of coordinates (maybe coordinate pairs #1 and #3 are the closest), so you'll have to use a nested for-loop. Currently you're trying to find distances between *adjacent* coordinates (so you only check distance between #1 - #2, and #2 - #3, etc.).
6. When you iterate over `storageDist` you're using the wrong index.
7. Check that your distance calculation is correct. Remember you should subtract x-coordinates from each other, and y-coordinates from each other.

Please try to fix these issues. (Points 4 and 5 will probably be the trickiest to fix -- you can post a new question if you're still stuck after a while, but at least fix the other issues first.)

Answer (score 0):

It should be appriciated that you are trying hard instead of searching for ready made solutions. Answer 1 is pointing the errors nicely. Just to encourage you, here is the error free version of your own code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class coordinates {
public static double distance(int w, int x, int y, int z) {
        double xdist = Math.pow(y-w, 2);
        double ydist = Math.pow(z-x, 2);
        double output = Math.sqrt(xdist + ydist);
        return output;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String>storage = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer>storageInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Double>storageDist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    String values = "";
    String inArray;
    String[]holder;
    int convert;
    while(true) {
        values = input.nextLine();
        if(values.equals("-1"))
        {
            break;
        }
        storage.add(values);
    }
//convert coordinates to int
    for(int i = 0; i<storage.size();i++) {
        inArray = storage.get(i);
        holder = inArray.split(",");
        for(int j=0;j<holder.length;j++)
        {
            convert = Integer.parseInt(holder[j]);
            storageInt.add(convert);
        }
    }
    //store distance
    double dist = distance(storageInt.get(0),    storageInt.get(1),storageInt.get(2),storageInt.get(3));
    storageDist.add(dist);
        //smallest distance
    Collections.sort(storageDist);
for (int i=0;i<storageDist.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(storageDist.get(0));
    }
    }
    }
```